# jquery scrollers which works on mouse over not click for panel links

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

i'm looking for a scroller similar to jcarousel but one that changes panels on mouse over not click of the external links

e.g

main nav = home  - about - services

on mouse over of home scroll to home panel etc

anyone know of one i can download

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use just [`jcarousel`](http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/), it adds the next and previous icons and gives them a class `jcarousel-next` and `jcarousel-prev`, you could add a [`.mouseover()`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/), check the icon hasn't been disabled by checking for the class `jcarousel-next-disabled`, then firing a [`.click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/) on the item you are hovering over.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#mycarousel').jcarousel();

    $('.jcarousel-next').mouseover(function(){
        if(!$(this).hasClass("jcarousel-next-disabled"))
            $(this).click();
    });

    $('.jcarousel-prev').mouseover(function(){
        if(!jQuery(this).hasClass("jcarousel-prev-disabled"))
            $(this).click();
    });
});
```

**See a simple working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/k2dRW/)**

---

If what you are really after is panel's displaying data, like pages, there are lots of examples: [Animated tabbed content with jQuery](http://www.gayadesign.com/diy/animated-tabbed-content-with-jquery/) see it working [here](http://www.gayadesign.com/scripts/tabbed/)

Alternatively you could use the [jQuery UI `.tabs()`](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Tabs) and add a little switchery for the mouse over - it already supports animations, [see an example](http://jsfiddle.net/Scoobler/jGZ6w/2/)

Comment: thanks scoobler i like the animated tabbed content one, thats what i'm trying to achieve but with jcarousel. think i'm using the wrong script! problem i had was with the jcarousel and page link along the top if you moved the mouse fast it wouldn't complete the previous animation or start the next

Comment: No problem Adam, it does sound like you are trying to adapt jcarousel to do the job you want, but the animated tabbed content seems more like it is designed to do what you want. Glad to have been some help!